# cakephp, how can I add a class to the url instead of the image

Tags: php, cakephp

I wonder what is the most cakey way to do this. When I do:

```
echo $this->Html->image('uploadimage.gif', array('alt'=>'Upload Image', 'class'=>'nyroModal', 'url'=>'#test'));
```

It outputs:

```
<a href="#test"><img src="/img/uploadimage.gif" alt="Upload Image" class="nyroModal" /></a>
```

I need it to be:

```
<a href="#test" class="nyroModal"><img src="/img/uploadimage.gif" alt="Upload Image"/></a>
```

IE the class is applied to the link rather than the image. How can I do that?

thanks :)

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply. I'm a bit of a newb so not completely sure what your telling me to do. I changed the javascript to: $(function() {  $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();}); But that didn't work. Also changed the cake stuff to 'class'=>'nyroModal img' but that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used cakePHP but for what I read online instead of giving a url to the image you can do it the other way around, create a link and pass an image, the result should be something like this:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("uploadimage.gif", array("alt" => "Upload Image")),
    "#test",
    array("escape" => "false", "class" => "nyroModal")
);
?>
```

For more info on `link` you can go here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link

Comment: careful! you need to pass escape=>false - otherwise the image html is ecaped! => $this->Html->link($image, $url, array('escape'=>false, 'class'=>...));

Comment: @mark thanks, edited to add that. It seems I did not read carefully.